# Subtract 1 week from date format YYWW in R

Tags: r, date

I have a vector of dates in the following format: YYWW. For example 1101 is year 2011 and week 01 of that year and so on.

```
dates <- c(1101, 1105, 1201, 1212)

# Create the dataframe
df <- data.frame(date = dates)

df <- df %>%
  mutate(year = substr(date, 1, 2),
         week = as.integer(substr(date, 3, 4))) %>%
  mutate(
    year = as.integer(paste0("20", year)),
    week = if_else(week < 10, paste0("0", week), as.character(week)))
```

What I would like is to create a date variable and subtract from each observation one week.
So 1101 will become 1052 and so on.

Desired output is the following:

```
New_date
1052
1104
1152
1211
```

Thanks

Comment: `format(as.Date(paste0(dates, 1), '%y%W%u') - 7, "%y%V")`